# Acessar URL sem receber a resposta

Tags: c#, .net, http

Eu tenho uma página que realiza diversas tarefas. Essa página está aberta aos usuários finais do sistema, que podem acessá-la via navegador.

Em determinadas situações eu gostaria de disparar o processamento da página com uma aplicação console. Algo do tipo:

```
using System.Net;

/* .. SNIP .. */

WebClient foo = new WebClient();
foo.DownloadString("http://siteDaAplicacao.com.br/Pagina.aspx");
```

Meu problema: todos os métodos da classe WebClient, até onde sei, vão trazer a resposta HTTP completa do servidor. Então mesmo que eu não utilize a resposta - por exemplo, chamando a versão assíncrona do método `WebClient.DownloadString`, em algum momento vai entrar na aplicação console uma string com a representação de todo o HTML que minha página monta normalmente.

Existe alguma maneira, em .NET, de fazer uma requisição HTTP (de preferência mas não obrigatoriamente GET) e informar ao servidor que eu não quero a resposta?

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que você deseja. Você quer fazer a requisição mas não quer que venha alguma resposta? É isso mesmo? Qual o objetivo? Saber se o servidor está vivo? Você só não quer perder tempo em receber a resposta?

Comment: @bigown eu só quero disparar o processo, e a resposta pode ser muito grande. Vou fazer a mesma requisição de uma vez para várias páginas e a resposta combinada delas pode ter vários megas. Como a resposta é irrelevante para a aplicação console, gostaria de não ter que receber toda essa informação.

Comment: Pode ser com `async`? Você já sabe a solução, né? :)

Comment: @bigown mesmo que eu use os métodos assíncronos a resposta do servidor ainda é enviada para a minha máquina. É isso que eu quero evitar.

Comment: Até onde eu sei, não há como evitar qualquer resposta, talvez possa evitar o conteúdo vir. E ainda não imagino a razão de precisar disto.

Comment: Eu até conheço uma maneira de evitar a resposta pra minha aplicação - manipular os cabeçalhos dos pacotes TCP pra eles informarem que o endereço de resposta é outro. Mas não posso fazer isso. E nem seria muito legal se o endereço que eu colocasse existisse, o destinatário poderia encarar como um DDoS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez não dê com o `WebClient` mas parece dar com `WebRequest`, basta pedir apenas o `HEAD` e não os dados. Não pode usar o `GET`, este retorna todo o conteúdo. Acredito que é o melhor que dá para fazer. Para isto precisa *setar* o [método da requisição](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.method?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Net_WebRequest_Method) da classe [`WebRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0). Tem exemplos na documentação sem usar o `HEAD` mas bastaria fazer isto:

```
webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
```

Achei uma [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5353821/221800) que fez isto:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            System.Net.WebRequest wc = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.imdb.com"); //args[0]);

            ((HttpWebRequest)wc).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.153.1 Safari/525.19";
            wc.Timeout = 1000;
            wc.Method = "HEAD";
            WebResponse res = wc.GetResponse();
            var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());

            Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

---

<sub>Estava respondendo quando o AP mostrou que eu estava no caminho errado. Vou deixar aqui para que possa ajudar alguém. Mas esta parte não responde ao que foi perguntado.</sub>

Essencialmente é pegar com a [versão assíncrona do método usado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#overloads), assim a aplicação "presa" não fica esperando pela resposta ([uma das formas com `Webrequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/making-asynchronous-requests?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). Você ainda irá recebê-la, poderá descartar ou não, mas precisa receber de alguma forma.

```
using System.Net;

/* .. SNIP .. */

WebClient foo = new WebClient();
foo.DownloadStringAsync("http://siteDaAplicacao.com.br/Pagina.aspx");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/DownloadWeb.cs).

Gostei da pergunta porque acabei aprendendo algumas coisas que não sabia, embora soubesse da essência. Descobri que o termo usado para isto é *fire and forget*. Achei [alguns](https://web.archive.org/web/20160220033318/https://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/fire-and-forget-class-for-asp-net) [exemplos](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/09/asynchronous-fire-and-forget-with-lambdas.aspx/) como [este](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20060727.asp) que funcionam de uma forma diferente (basicamente saiu dessa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2178340/221800)).

Comment: Se algum dia nos encontrarmos na rua me lembra de te pagar uma cerveja por esta resposta.

Comment: Vários dias depois... acho que usar `TRACE` ao invés `HEAD` pode ser ainda mais econômico se o site atender esse tipo de requisição :) Ainda assim, sua resposta salvou a minha vida, então obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: @Renan não sei se muda muita coisa e não sei se vale o esforço mas dependendo do que for fazer pode ser até o mais correto.